# What is the difference between myDate and Int(myDate)

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project which needs to understand a VB code and I'm particulary stucked on one line.

I've looked on google and asked help from my collegue but I didn't find the answer.

Here is the line :

```
   BegHour = myDate - Int(myDate)
```

Comment: This removes the date component from the date and only leaves the time. (That is, it resets the date component to `1899-12-30`.) However the semicolon makes me wonder if it is in fact VBA code we are talking about.

Comment: For example, if myDate is ```2019-05-17 12:30 AM``` 
SO ```BegHour = "2019-05-17 12:30 AM" - "1899-12-30 12:30 AM"``` ?

Yes, it's VBA code but I put a semicolon as I am more familiar with JAVA. My bad

Comment: No, if `myDate` is `2019-05-17 12:30 AM`, then `BegHour = #2019-05-17 12:30 AM# - #2019-05-17#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually depends on what your `myDate` is declared. If we can assume that it is declared as

```
Dim myDate As Date
```

then it could contain a date including a time `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Since the integer part of a datetime is only the date without time eg if you do `Int(myDate)` you will only get the date parte `yyyy-mm-dd` without time.

Finally if you subtract the date of a datetime `BegHour = myDate - Int(myDate)` you will get only the time part `hh:mm:ss`.

#### Why is that?

Actually dates are saved as the amount of days since `1900-01-01` which is considered to be `1`. So for example `2019-05-17` is day number `43602` since `1900-01-01`. The time is a part of a day so `0.5` days means `12` hours for example.

Comment: `? CDate(1)` => `31/12/1899`

Comment: Yes, myDate is declared like this.
Oh okay !! Thank you, it was well explained.

Comment: @GSerg yes in VBA they corrected the Lotus 1-2-3 bug that existed in Excel formulas: See [Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year), but in formulas they did not correct it to be compatible. So we need to be careful because formula and VBA act differently until `1900-03-01` from then to now they act the same!

Answer (score 0):

Think of today, at 6pm : `"17/05/2019  18:00:00"`

This is held as a `Date` - which can be formatted in many ways but is held in memory as the number of days since 1899 = so 43602.75

So if `myDate` holds 43602.75 then `BegHour` would equate to:

`= 43602.75 - Int (43602.75)`

`= 43602.75 - 43602`

`= 0.75`

Which, if treated as a `DateTime` could be formatted to read `18:00` or `6pm` etc.